# How to persist old data in database while using EF Data Migrations

Tags: entity-framework-4, data-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I was thinking that the purpose of EF DataMigrations is to preserve old data while changing the database structure. Do I think right? But when I update the database with migrations all the old data is erased.

Do I make something wrong or maybe it isn't possible to use data migrations in this kind of scenario ?

this is DbContext:

```
public class CodeFirstContext : DbContext
   {
    public CodeFirstContext() : base ("ZenRandevuIzle")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; } 

    public DbSet<Takvim> Takvims { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Musteri> Musteris { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Randevu> Randevus { get; set; }

    public DbSet<SeansTuru> SeansTurus { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Hizmet> Hizmets { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Islem> Islems { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
    }
}
```

this is Global.asax:

```
  Database.SetInitializer<CodeFirstContext>(new CodeFirstContextInit());
```

this is migration Config:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CodeFirstContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What changes to database did you done?

Comment: if we change anything, all the data is erased.

Comment: Can you post your DbContext and Migrations Configurations? Are you using Auto or Manual migrations? did you accidentally leave the old ef code first db initializer that drops the database?

Answer (score 1):

Does the CodeFirstContextInit initialiser drop the database and recreate it (what is its base class?) normally I wouldn't have an initializer when using migrations.

Answer (score 1):

To use EF 4.3 Code First Data Migrations with an existing database you need to create an "empty" migration so that the Migration-History table is created and a baseline can be established.

The Steps outlined in this post should help http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/using-ef-4-3-code-first-migrations-with-an-existing-database

Comment: The provided link is dead